# select if column name exists in a list

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to select columns if they are contained in a list. The problem is that I get an error for the columns that don't exist.

Try 1:

```r
library(dplyr)

data(band_instruments)

desired_vars <- c("plays", "grade", "age")

is_desired_vars <- function(x) names(x) %in% desired_vars

band_instruments %>%
 select_if(.predicate = is_desired_vars)
```

Try 2:

```
desired_vars <- c("plays", "grade", "age")
band_instruments[, desired_vars]
```

More Details:

I would like the solution to generalize. There may be a dataframe that this function acts on which would contain all columns in the list, but some dataframes will not contain all of the columns in this list.

Comment: **band_instruments** data includes only 2 columns : *name , plays*.  So you can't call it like `band_instruments[, desired_vars]` .  If you call `band_instruments[, "plays"]` , you get an output.

Comment: The problem is that I would like the solution to generalize. There may be a dataframe that this function acts on which would contain all columns in the list, but some dataframes will not contain all of the columns in this list.

Comment: If you want to follow your setting, you can run :  `band_instruments[,is_desired_vars(band_instruments)]`

Comment: That is exactly what I was going for. Thanks!